# Domain not attached to the Cpanel

Tags: dns, whm

I registered domain on the WHM and create a new user cpanel with the domain, the domain is added to the cpanel. But when i try to browse the domain name it getting server DNS address could not be found.i updated the name servers with my server name, but nothing changed.

when i try to go through myip/~newuser it going fine to the site file, but with the domain name it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You have a DNS issue in this case. Please check your DNS zone with a tool like intoDns:
https://intodns.com/yourdomain.tld

See if you get any errors there. If you do, then you have issues with your DNS configuration. Be sure that you have create the parent DNS servers for your domain if you want to use the DNS from WHM (the parent DNS servers should point to your WHM server ip).

Try using external services to query your DNS server to see if it actually works (like MXToolBox etc). Or you can use **nslookup** or **dig** right from your WHM server by connecting via ssh.